# -awakeFromNib in UIView Category

Tags: ios, uiview, objective-c-category, awakefromnib

is it safe to write code in -awakeFromNib method on UIView Category.

```
UIView+XXXXXX.m

@implementation UIView (XXXXXX)

- (void) awakeFromNib {

    /* some code here */

}
```

@end

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour is undefined, and I would consider it not safe for that reason.

From the Apple docs:

> If the name of a method declared in a category is the same as a
>   method in the original class, or a method in another category on the
>   same class (or even a superclass), the behavior is undefined as to
>   which method implementation is used at runtime. This is less likely to
>   be an issue if you’re using categories with your own classes, but can
>   cause problems when using categories to add methods to standard Cocoa
>   or Cocoa Touch classes.

See:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html